# How to insert XML comments in Java code in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find a way to enable insertion of XML comments in Java code using the IntelliJ IDEA editor (v. 12 community edition).

I'm talking about comments like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="plainText">Plain text to encrypt</param>
/// <param name="key">Secret key</param>
/// <returns>Base64 encoded string</returns>
public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place keyboard caret above your method. Type `/**` then hit ENTER. Intellj will create a template JavaDoc comment to which you can add a description of parameters and return value , for example:

```
/**
 *  Encrypts plaintext using AES 128bit key and a Chain Block Cipher and returns a base64 encoded string  
 * 
 * @param plainText  Plain text to encrypt
 * @param key  Secret key
 * @return Base64 encoded string
 */
public String encrypt(String plainText, String key) throws ...
```

To see a pop-up window with the formatted comment text place the caret inside  /** ... */ and type `Ctrl+Q`

Comment: Yes, that's more like what I'm talking about. But what if I prefer XML comments instead of JavaDoc comments? Is there support for that in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I don't know of any  (Visual Studio) "XML comments" equivalent in java. In java Javadoc is the way to document methods and classes. API documentation can then be generated in html.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. If nobody has a better answer within a day or two I'll assume you're right and accept this one. (And I'll repeat again that I have actually seen these kind of comments in a Java program, so that's why I thought it should be possible to create them semi-automatically.)

Comment: Perhaps those xml comments you saw somewhere where created with [Doc-O-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/index.html) or [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/xmlcmds.html) which both support Xml Doc comments for C# and Java. These tools can integrate with IDEs such as with Visual Studio, but don't know if they support IntelliJ. To be sure ask 
on [IntelliJ forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=overview)

Answer (score 0):

Use {@code ... } Javadoc tag.
Look here: http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2008/08/adding-xml-to-javadoc-comments/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I'm talking about. https://coderwall.com/p/qbnmfg Maybe it's only a Visual Studio thing? But I have seen these kinds of comments in a Java program, so I was thinking it's more universal?